# NodeJS 8.10.0 - Azure (iisnode) - Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, mailgun

I'm hosting a NodeJs web app in Microsoft Azure, and I'm receiving the following error:

```
Sun Mar 25 2018 01:32:14 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated: SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server\helpers\email.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server\controllers\email.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
```

at the error line:

```
var Mailgun = require('mailgun-js');
```

The same application is working properly in another Azure Web App (same config between the two).
To setup the NodeJs version I'm using across all the web apps the WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION application setting.

I would expect this kind of error with older versions of nodejs, but not with the 8.10.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found that the web application with problems was created using a Microsoft template "Node JS Empty Web App".

This template left on the root of the web application the iisnode.yml file that was forcing the version 4.2.4, despite globally was used the 8.10.0.

```
nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\4.2.4\node.exe"
```

Removing the iisnode.yml solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by redeyes.
another approach is to edit the path with the version number
nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\8.10.x\node.exe"